# Defined a function but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: function-construction, computational-geometry

I'm trying to implement the [line-crossing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838329/how-can-i-check-if-two-segments-intersect) on Mathematica and I seem to be having trouble getting it to work. More specifically, I would like to know what is causing the function to not evaluate, and instead reproduce the code for the function as the output like in Out[142].

In case you would like to try the code on your own Mathematica to further analyze the issue, here's the code:

```
SegInter[{l1_: {p1_: {x1_, y1_}, p2_: {x2_, y2_}}, l2_: {p3_: {x3_, y3_}, 
 p4_: {x4_, y4_}}}] :=
(*Assume that Min[x1,x2]<Min[x3,x4]*)
If[Max[x1, x2] < Min[x3, x4], 
    If[(x1 == x2) && (x3 == x4), 
        If[x1 == x2,
            (*Line 1 is vertical but not line 2*) If[(x3 - x1)*(x4 - x1) > 0, False, True], 
            If[x3 == x4,
                (*Line 2 is vertical but not line 1*) If[(x1 - x3)*(x2 - x3) > 0, False, True],
                (*Neither line is vertical*) Module[{a1, a2},
                                                    a1 = (y1 - y2)/(x1 - x2); 
                                                    a2 = (y3 - y4)/(x3 - x4); 
                                                    If[a1 == a2,(*Parallel*)False, Module[{b1, b2, xa},
                                                                                          b1 = y1 - a1*x1;
                                                                                          b2 = y3 - a2*x3; 
                                                                                          xa = (b2 - b1)/(a1 - a2); 
                                                                                          If[(xa < Max[Min[x1, x2], Min[x3, x4]]) || (xa > Min[Max[x1, x2], Max[x3, x4]]), False, True]
                                                      ]
                                                    ]
          ]
      ]
  ],(*Parallel vertical*)False], False]
```

[image]

Comment: Copy your code into the question.

Comment: I just did, sorry it took a while to format

Comment: Are you aware of [`RegionIntersection`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html) and the other geometric calculation functions? If you just need the functionality, that may be a more direct route. Of course, there's nothing wrong in reimplementing the algorithm though.

Comment: Hmm, what a mess; try using the definition `SegInter[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}, {{x3_, y3_}, {x4_, y4_}}] := (* stuff *)` instead... but you still have a few bugs to catch. BTW: you might want to look at [this Graphics Gems entry](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=ue0C-a59db0C&pg=PA199).

Comment: @MarcoB I'll look into the `RegionIntersection` function! I only recently started using Mathematica so I'm still pretty clueless about a lot of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stopped debugging after the first line.

**The problem** is you need `p1 : {x1_, x2_}` and you have `p1_ : {x1_, x2_}` where `{x1_, x2_}` is `Optional` for missing entry.

Which makes `xi_` not associated with an input at all, they will appear only when the input is missing. Unless you fix your code you can only use `pi` references. But the very outer statement is `If` which can't verify the condition.

A minimal example:

```
f[x_: {x1_, x2_}] := {x, {x1, x2}}

f[{a, b}]
```

> ```
> {{a, b}, {x1, x2}}
> ```

```
f[]
```

> ```
> {{x1_, x2_}, {x1, x2}}
> ```

---

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x : {x1_, x2_}] := {x, {x1, x2}}

f[{a, b}]
```

> ```
> {a, b}
> ```

```
f[]
```

> ```
> f[]
> ```

Comment: I tried removing all the pi and li references to make `SegInter[{{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}, {{x3_, y3_}, {x4_, y4_}}}]`, and now it seems to at least give `True` or `False` like I intended it to. Ofc it still needs to be fixed since it claims that `(-1,0),(1,0)` and `(0,-1),(0,1)` don't intersect, but that's probably because I implemented it incorrectly. Thank you!

Comment: @2012ssohn I'm glad I could help, p.s. consider using `Which` instead of nested `Ifs`.

Comment: @2012, that was what I meant by "you still need to catch a few bugs" in my previous comment. ;)